# Hibernate Mapping 1 to Many

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have an application where user can register and then create a collection of assets, so, I can assume that there are mainly 2 entities `User` and `Asset`, with a `1-to-Many` relationship from `User` to `Asset`.

So, what should be the most appropriate `hibernate-mapping` for the above mentioned scenario, and also, if I have to list all the assets and their creator details on a single call,

what should be the best approach for that as well?

Please give your solutions

Comment: please add some code of these two class `User` and `Asset` because we cannot identify what exactly attributes are inside these classes actually.

Comment: Better you go to any tutorial site and study about all four mapping.

Comment: Let's assume User class has attributes id,name,email and list of Asset and Asset class has attributes id, name, category, owner which is of User class type

Answer (score 2):

If you have annotations enabled in your project. We can do it as :

```
//In User Entity class
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user") // "user" is the name of instance variable in Asset class
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) // To avoid the LazyFetchException
private List<Asset> assetList;

// in Asset Entity class
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id") // name specifies the name of column name in DB
private User user;
```